# Skip specifying function arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have the following function in Python (see it on [Trinket](https://trinket.io/python/eb721e1555)):

```
def foo(a=1, b=2):
  print(a);
  print(b)

foo(,4)
```

When I run `foo(,4)`, I want it to use the default when the first argument is not provided, and use the provided value if it's available. I.e. it should print:

```
1
4
```

Is this possible in Python? And, if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use keyword arguments.

```
foo(b=4)
```